# Trace route in real time Maps api V3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I want the user to be able to plot a route while walking, in real time. I already have the user's location, but I do not know how to progress.

Can someone help me?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Maps Geolocation</title>

<style>

.success{
 background-color:#6F9!important;
 color:#000!important;
 }

#status{
 padding:5px;
 background-color:#000;
 color:#fff;} 

</style>
</head>

<body>

<section id="wrapper">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <article>
      <p><span id="status">Please wait whilst we try to locate you...</span></p>
    </article>
<script>


function success(position) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');
  
  if (s.className == 'success') {
    return;
  }
  
  s.innerHTML = "found you!";
  s.className = 'success';
  
  var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
  mapcanvas.id = 'mapcanvas';
  mapcanvas.style.height = '800px';
  mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';
    
  document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);
  
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: latlng,
   // styles: styles,
    mapTypeControl: false
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), myOptions);
  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng, 
      map: map, 
      title:"You are here!"
  });
}

function error(msg) {
  var s = document.querySelector('#status');
  s.innerHTML = typeof msg == 'string' ? msg : "failed";
  s.className = 'fail';
  
  // console.log(arguments);
}

if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}

</script> 
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

I want while the user is walking the route is drawn on the map

Answer (score 1):

You may try using these:

- For walking specific directions, use [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests).

  With this API, `travelMode` is a required field when sending directions requests. However, this doesn't provide real time responses (as far as I know).
- To get realtime locations, use [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation).

  This API is device specific, which means that browsers or devices that you use must support geolocation to be able to use this API.

  **Note**: Applications that want to perform geolocation must support the [W3C Geolocation standard](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). I would also suggest that you check [6 Use-Cases and Requirements](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#usecases).

After getting the current location or directions, you may plot the route using [Polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines). As stated in the documentation,

> The `Polyline` class defines a linear overlay of connected line segments on the map. A `Polyline` object consists of an array of `LatLng` locations, and creates a series of line segments that connect those locations in an ordered sequence.

Here's a simple polyline implementation code:

```
// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of William
// Kingsford Smith's first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and
// Brisbane, Australia.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
    {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
    {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
    {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

  flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I would suggest that you check [Google Maps Terms of Service License Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10) specifically those restrictions regarding Maps API implementations.

For better understanding, please try going through the documentations and you may also check these additional references:

- [Map Coverage Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/coverage) which shows the coverage details on a country-by-country basis.
- PubNub Articles for sample implementation codes

  - [Google Maps Geolocation Tracking in Realtime with JavaScript](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-30-google-maps-geolocation-tracking-in-realtime-with-javascript/)
  - [Broadcasting Geolocation Data with HTML5 Location Services](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-28-broadcasting-geolocation-data-with-javascript-and-html5-location-services/)

Hope this helps!